# Can I have multiple partition keys in one query?

Tags: linq, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a range query, which might cover several partitions. 
Can I specify multiple partitions in one query? Should I better run a query per partition and then join the results?

Example:

```
.CreateQuery<Segment>()
.Where(s => s.PartitionKey == "A" || s.PartitionKey == "B")
```

Can I do contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I specify multiple partitions in one query?

Yes, you can do that.

> Should I better run a query per partition and then join the results?

Generally speaking it is recommended approach but it depends a lot on your application. I would highly recommend reading up on [`Azure Storage Table Design Guide`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/).

> Can I do contains?

No. `Contains` is not supported. For a list of supported operators, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135725.aspx.